# Updating php72-php-fpm to the latest php 7.4 on centos 7

Tags: centos, php, centos7, php-fpm

Im a bit of a newbie at server administration and I was wondering if I could get some tips on updating my PHP version.

When I first setup my server, I followed a tutorial and managed to get php 7.2 up and going, but now I want to update the php 7.4 and im not really sure how.

I'm running a CentOS 7 box, and I setup my original PHP using the following commands;

```
yum install yum-utils
yum install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72

yum install php72 php-cli php72-php-fpm php72-php-gd php72-php-json php72-php-mbstring php72-php-mysqlnd php72-php-xml php72-php-xmlrpc php72-php-opcache php72-php-zip php72-php-soap php72-php-bcmath php72-php-imagick

systemctl start php72-php-fpm
systemctl enable php72-php-fpm
```

There were some files edited as well, for instance;

```
/etc/opt/remi/php72/php.ini
/etc/opt/remi/php72/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

Any help would be really greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo yum -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum -y install https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
```

Enable Remi and EPEL Repository
Install both previously downloaded packages and enable Remi PHP 7 repo:

```
sudo yum -y install yum-utils
sudo yum-config-manager --enable remi-php74

sudo yum update
sudo yum install php php-cli
```

You can then install additional packages example:

```
sudo yum install php  php-cli php-fpm php-mysqlnd php-zip php-devel php-gd php-mcrypt php-mbstring php-curl php-xml php-pear php-bcmath php-json'
```

Now check the version
    php -v

You should be asked whether you would like to keep your php.ini file unchanged or not during the install.

Comment: as always.... simply follow the Wizard instructions... https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Comment: Error:
 Problem: package remi-release-7.7-2.el7.remi.noarch requires epel-release = 7, but none of the providers can be installed